# Почему не загружаются картинки при первом запуске react native приложения на реальном ios устройстве?

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

Почему первом запуске картинка может не отображаться?

```
<Image source={require(./assets/onboard-2.png)} style={styles.image}/>
```

В стилях:

```
image: {
    width: 300,
    height: 300
  }
```

При этом показывается сообщение:

> would like to find and connect to devices on your local network

А в консоле xcode ошибка:

> Could not find image >file:///private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/..../assets/src/assets/onboard-2.png

Повторяется только при первом деплое на реальный iphone через xcode. При след запуске через xcode ошибка не повторяется.

Использую react-native 0.70.2. XCode 14.3, ios 14.